# how to add window-decorations to GUI-applications on Ubuntu (without default WM)

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want to develop a simple window manager(WM) with GTK3 for Ubuntu.
(Of course, I know using GTK3 isn't a good way to make WM, so it's just for self-use)

I'm trying various ways to add **window decolrations**(particularly:titlebar) to GUI-applications, 
but I've never succeeded.

Can I do it with GTK3? (or do I have to use Xlib?)

a part of codes :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...

void run_terminal(){

    ...

    if(_event->keyval==32)system("xterm"); // runs xterm when I press SPACE key
    return TRUE;
}
```

shell script (for testing) :

```
#/bun/sh

gcc main.c  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)

sudo xinit ./a.out -- :1
```

Thank you.